# Code not functioning properly outside JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, forms, browser, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7m7uK/940/

This seems to work fine in the JSFiddle but not when i move it to the actual code/browser...it also doesn't work when I create a new jsfiddle. The sliding content only shows up covering the  previous link so then can't close again

Anyone know what's up?

```
$('#loginPanel1').click(function () {

    if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {

        $('#userNav').show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500);
    } else {

        $('#userNav').hide('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500);
    }
});

$('#loginPanel2').click(function () {

    if ($('#userNav').is(':hidden')) {

        $('#userNav').show('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500);
    } else {

        $('#userNav').hide('slide', {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, you are putting it in the onload, that means it already uses the `$(document).ready(function() { */ code here */ });` style of running your code only after the dom & scripts are loaded. In your new ones, you probably simply add it in the head but not in a "document-ready" way?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a proper problem description. WHat doesn't work? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? What error do you get? What did you debugging efforts turn up?

Comment: sorry I'm new to JS...I tried wrapping it in '$(document).ready(function() { */ code here */ });' however it still doesn't work?

Comment: Silly question but did you add your jquery reference? What does the console say

Comment: I want it to output what happens in the JS Fiddle (content slides out) but when I move it to my actual code the slide function doesnt work..

Comment: '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>' I have this in the head

Comment: You also need to add jquery-ui.js, that is added in the External Resources section of your fiddle

Comment: Can't believe I never saw that in the first place, cheers!

Comment: Oh i see you got it now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok try the following.

1. Make sure jquery.js is added
2. Make sure the jquery-ui.js is added
3. And wrap your code in `$(function(){ });`

That should be in i think.